# output is getting printed two times in the file generated in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]

I am trying to print the confusion matrix for each two column of my dataset as I have that kind of dataset using the code as attached. But I am getting output printed two times.

I am not sure why the output is getting printed for two times. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code and data not as images. You can share your data using `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general foreach returns its values, which will be printed. To suppress that you can wrap the `foreach` loop in a call to the `invisible` function. e.g.

````
---
title: ''
output: html_document
---



```{r echo=TRUE}
library(foreach)

foreach (i=1) %do% print(i) #prints twice
invisible(foreach (i=1) %do% print(i)) #prints once


```
````